# Flutter Animation controller Invalid reference to 'this' expression

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter spinkkit plugin issue is its showing an error on vsync this. `Invalid reference to 'this' expression.`

final spinkit = SpinKitSquareCircle(
color: kPrimaryColor,
size: 50.0,
controller:  AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200)),
);

So somewhere I read that I need to place it inside init state

So if I place this in init state its showing the error Undefined name 'spinkit'. where I am using spinner.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to `extend` your class with `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`. This enables you to use `AnimationController`.
And if you already extend a class with the above provider then you can try following answer. Make sure to make your `spinkit` variable `late final` as well.

You have to place that line inside `initState` method, as follow:

```
late final spinkit;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    spinkit = SpinKitSquareCircle( color: kPrimaryColor, size: 50.0, controller: AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200)), );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

for `Invalid reference to 'this' expression.` you have to add `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` you can check it below.

```
class test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _testState createState() => _testState();
}

class _testState extends State<test> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    final spinkit = SpinKitSquareCircle(
      color: kPrimaryColor,
      size: 50.0,
      controller: AnimationController(
          vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```